# Trying to read elements in an array using a for loop

Tags: perl

I'm trying to read elements from an array using a for loop, but I can't seem to get it working right.  When I run the program, it prints out a weird "HASH", or doesn't print out anything.  Can anyone help?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $he;
my @selections = {"Hamburger","Frankfurter","French Fries","Large Coke","Medium Coke","Small Coke","Onion Rings"};
my @prices = {3.49, 2.19, 1.69, 1.79, 1.59, 1.39, 1.19};

for($he= 0; $he<= 6; $he++)
{
      print "@selections[$he]";
      print "@prices[$he]\n";
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't hardcode that "6". `for (my $he= 0; $he<= 6; $he++)` should be `for (my $he=0; $he<@selections; $he++)`, and it would be more readable as `for my $he (0..$#selections)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you put `{}`, you explicitly ask `perl` to make a reference to a `HASH`. What you seems to need instead is using parenthesis to declare an `ARRAY`.

So :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

my @selections = (
    "Hamburger",
    "Frankfurter",
    "French Fries",
    "Large Coke",
    "Medium Coke",
    "Small Coke",
    "Onion Rings"
);
my @prices = (3.49, 2.19, 1.69, 1.79, 1.59, 1.39, 1.19);

for(my $he = 0; $he <= 6; $he++)
{
    print "$selections[$he]=$prices[$he]\n";
}
```

Moreover, making arrays is more fun and less boring like that :

```
my @selections = qw/foo bar base/;
```

but it only works when you don't have any space for values.

**NOTES**

- I recommend you to use `use warnings;` all the times
- don't write `@selections[$he]` but `$selections[$he]`
- no need to predeclare `$he` in the whole scope, see where I declare it
- a better approach (depends of your needs) is to use a `HASH` instead of two `ARRAYS` :

like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l
use strict; use warnings;

my %hash = (
    "Hamburger" => 3.49,
    "Frankfurter" => 2.19,
    "French Fries" => 1.69,
    "Large Coke" => 1.79,
    "Medium Coke" => 1.59,
    "Small Coke" => 1.39,
    "Onion Rings" => 1.19
);

foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
    print $key . "=" . $hash{$key};
}
```